# where is difference between this two snippets?

Tags: sql, oracle

Thanks for your interested

I have 2 sql snippets following, I tried it on Oracle and it showed 2 difference results.

```
select distinct s.course_no, count(*) amt
    from section s, enrollment e
    where s.section_id = e.section_id
    group by s.course_no
    having count(*) >= 8;

select distinct s.course_no, count(*) amt
    from section s, enrollment e
    where s.section_id = e.section_id
    group by s.course_no, e.section_id, s.section_id
    having count(*) >= 8;
```

As way which I got, I want count based on course_no, so I only declare group by s.course_no, why section_id affect to query result?!

Comment: Obviously they are different because their `group by` columns are different

Comment: This because of functionality of `GROUP BY`. For your case you could image that 1 `course_no` may has many different `section_id`, so if you `GROUP BY` both, then instead of only 1 `course_no`, you got many sub-group with that `course_no` and each of those many `section_id`.

Comment: We don't know your database. How is a course_no treated? Does course_no 123 always refer to the same course? Or is a course_no only meaningful within a section, so that course_no 123 in section 1 can refer to a different course from course_no 123 in section 2?

Comment: Why are you using that old join syntax? Are you working in Oracle 8i or older? Or are these just old queries that you are working on? Use ANSI joins instead: `from section s inner join enrollment e on s.section_id = e.section_id`. And what made you (or someone else) put `DISTINCT` into the queries? It doesn't make any sense there and looks like a kind of fight at windmills to me.

Answer (score 1):

There are differences between 2 script through the list of GROUP BY columns. For example, if your 1st query return this following output-

```
Course_no    Count
A            18
B            10
C            7 -- This row will excluded from output result
               -- set as count is lest then 8
```

For differences in list of GROUP BY column, your result will be different as below as you added 2 new column in the GROUP BY-

```
Course_no    section_id(e)    section_id(s)    Count
A            1                1                8  -- Show
A            1                2                6  -- Do not show
A            2                1                4  -- Do not show
                                         Total=18

B            1                1                5  -- Do not show
B            1                2                5  -- Do not show
                                         Total=10

C            1                1                4  -- Do not show
C            2                1                3  -- Do not show
                                         Total=7
```

For the second script's output, you will not see column section_id(e) & section_id(s) in output as they are not part of SELECT. I just add those columns for your reference to understand how the results will be distributed internally. You will only see columns Course_NO and Count.

For your filter having count(*) >= 8 you will only see one row as I put remarks after the row as --Show. All other rows will be excluded from the output because of your having clause.

Answer (score 0):

These 2 queries are different for result.

```
select distinct s.course_no, count(*) amt
    from section s, enrollment e
    where s.section_id = e.section_id
    group by s.course_no
    having count(*) >= 8;
```

Since in above query you choose only `course_no` in group by so it is calculating each record for distinct `course_no` column.

But

```
select distinct s.course_no, count(*) amt
    from section s, enrollment e
    where s.section_id = e.section_id
    group by s.course_no, e.section_id, s.section_id
    having count(*) >= 8;
```

In this query you select only `course_no` in your select statement but pass `section_id` in `group by`, hence records are calculated on behalf of distinct pair value of `course_no` and `section_id`.

Answer (score 0):

A course_no can be used accross sections.

With sections

```
+------------+-----------+
| section_id | course_no |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 |       123 | (and 10 enrollments for this section)
|          2 |       123 | (and 10 enrollments for this section)
|          3 |       123 | (and 20 enrollments for this section)
+------------+-----------+
```

you'd get

```
+-----------+----------+
| course_no | count(*) |
+-----------+----------+
|       123 |       40 |
+-----------+----------+
```

for the first query, because there are 40 enrollments for that course_no in total.

The second query, however, gets you rows per section_id and course_no first

```
+-----------+----------+
| course_no | count(*) |
+-----------+----------+
|       123 |       10 | (for section 1)
|       123 |       10 | (for section 2)
|       123 |       20 | (for section 3)
+-----------+----------+
```

of which you remove duplicates with `DISTINCT`. There are two lines for course_no 123 and count(*) = 10, so you remove one of these. You end up with

```
+-----------+----------+
| course_no | count(*) |
+-----------+----------+
|       123 |       10 |
|       123 |       20 |
+-----------+----------+
```

As a rule of thumb:

- It is very seldom that we `GROUP BY` columns that we don't also put into the `SELECT` clause.
- It is very seldom that we use `DISTINCT` on an aggregation result.

If you are doing one of the two things, reconsider why you are doing it. You are doing even both in the second query, which leads to strange results.